How to fetch current user email in Vue component and check whether this email matches with john@gmail.com or not?
When the current user is foe@gmail.com or isn't john@gmail.com the file still is being uploading.
I am expecting whether the current user email matches with john@gmail.com file will be uploaded otherwise won't be uploaded. In my FileUpload.vue:
<template>
    <MenuItem v-slot="{ active }">
        <a href="#" class="text-gray-700 block px-4 py-2 text-sm relative">
            Upload Files
            <input @change="onChange" type="file" class="absolute left-0 sm:top-0 bottom-0 sm:right-0 cursor-pointer opacity-0" multiple>
        </a>
    </MenuItem>
</template>

<script>
import { emitter, FILE_UPLOAD_STARTED, showErrorDialog } from "@/event-bus.js";
import { MenuItem } from "@headlessui/vue";
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    components: {
        MenuItem
    },
    data() {
        return {
            userEmail: '',
            showUploadButton: false,
            errorFetchingEmail: false
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        this.fetchUserEmail();
    },
    methods: {
        fetchUserEmail() {
            axios.get('/api/user')
                .then(response => {
                    this.userEmail = response.data.email;
                    if(this.userEmail === 'john@gmail.com'){
                        this.showUploadButton = true;
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error fetching user email:', error);
                    this.errorFetchingEmail = true;
                });
        },
        onChange(ev) {
            if (this.userEmail === 'john@gmail.com' &&  this.showUploadButton === true) {
                emitter.emit(FILE_UPLOAD_STARTED, ev.target.files);
            } else {
                showErrorDialog("File upload not allowed for this user.");
            }
        }
    }
};
</script>

And my api.php, when I upload the file as john@gmail.com the error "File upload not allowed for this user." shows and Error fetching user email......shows
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')
    ->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
//new

//new
//Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')
//    ->get('/user-email', [UserController::class, 'getUserEmail']);
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')
    ->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user()->email;
    });


You can use axios together with an async method in methods to make a get request to your backend:
async getUserEmail() {
  try {
    await axios.get('/user').then((result) => {
      this.userEmail = result.data.userEmail
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('err', err);
  }
};

Then, you can compare the emails.
